# How to bind data from Web API in Aurelia JS?

Tags: aurelia

I have json data which I get from call Web API. Code as below

```
export class App {

constructor() {

    this.empRecords = null;
    this.fetchEmployees();
}

fetchEmployees() {
    httpClient.fetch('http://localhost:61517/odata/emps')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.empRecords = data;
        });
}
```

}

When i bind this json data in html table.  html code as below :

```
 <table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><b>First Name</b></td>
            <td><b>Last Name</b></td>
            <td><b>Age</b></td>
            <td><b>Gender</b></td>
            <td><b>Department</b></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr repeat.for="emp of empRecords">

            <td>${emp.fname}</td>
            <td>${emp.lname}</td>
            <td>${emp.age}</td>
            <td>${emp.gender}</td>
            <td>${emp.department}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

it is unable to bind data in html table. It showing following error :

Uncaught Error: Value for 'empRecords' is non-repeatable

How can i bind the data in html table in aurelia js.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that before the response arrives, the array is null, which, as the error says, not repeatable. You either guard the `repeat.for` element with an `if` or set the `empRecords` property to an empty array rather than `null`. You can even use both.

Approach 1:

```
<tbody if.bind="empRecords && empRecords.length">
  <tr repeat.for="emp of empRecords">
    <td>${emp.fname}</td>
    <td>${emp.lname}</td>
    <td>${emp.age}</td>
    <td>${emp.gender}</td>
    <td>${emp.department}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody if.bind="!empRecords || !empRecords.length">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">No data</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Approach 2:

```
export class App {

  constructor() {
    this.empRecords = [];
    this.fetchEmployees();
  }
}
```

By setting the `empRecords` to `[]` rather than `null`, it becomes repeatable just it will be empty.

Also, based on your feedback, your response structure contains the values within an embedded property. Modify the fetchData method like this:

```
fetchEmployees() {
  var self = this;

  httpClient.fetch('http://localhost:61517/odata/emps')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      self.empRecords = data.value;
    });
}
```

Comment: Then I assume your response is incorrect. Log it to the console where you assign it to `this.empRecords` please and see what it is. My guess is that the array is wrapped inside an object. If that is the case, just extract the array from there.

Comment: i have json data for that i call odata api

Comment: And what does that return?

Comment: {"odata.metadata":"http://localhost:61517/odata/$metadata#emps","value":[{"id":1004,"fname":"jai","lname":"pundir","age":23,"gender":"Male","department":"IT"},{"id":1005,"fname":"ram","lname":"singh","age":24,"gender":"male","department":"HR"}]}

Comment: You need to bind it to the `value`. `this.empRecords = data.value;` I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not an array, but contains a `value` that contains the array you want to bind to. Something like this should do the trick:

```
httpClient.fetch('http://localhost:61517/odata/emps')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        this.empRecords = data.value;
    });
```

Edit: as suggested in the other answer, you should also initialize your empRecords by setting

```
this.empRecords = []
```

in the constructor.

JSON returned by httprequest:

```
{
  "odata.metadata":"localhost:61517/odata/$metadata#emps",
  "va‌​lue": [
    {
      "id":1004,
      "fn‌​ame":"jai",
      "lname":"‌​pundir",
      "age":23,
      "ge‌​nder":"Male",
      "depart‌​ment":"IT"
    },
    {
      "id":10‌​05,
      "fname":"ram",
      "ln‌​ame":"singh",
      "age":2‌​4,
      "gender":"male",
      "d‌​epartment":"HR"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`this` is not referencing `class App()` when you call it inside

```
.then(data => {
    this.empRecords = data;
});
```

I'm not sure but try using:

```
export class App {

    constructor() {
        this.empRecords = null;
        this.fetchEmployees();
    }

    fetchEmployees() {
        var self = this;

        httpClient.fetch('http://localhost:61517/odata/emps')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                self.empRecords = data;
            });
    }
```

Comment: zeropublix error remove but still does not bind the data to table

Comment: hey at least 1 thing gone :D

Comment: Arrow functions don't modify `this` unlike regular functions. The transpiler will sort that out for you, therefore it's redundant to manually capture `this`.

Comment: @Balázs thanks for that information. did not know that.